# Need help/support for validating a possible architecture Cloud-Edge with k3s

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I would like to know if there is possible to build the following architecture Cloud-Edge with k3s:

On cloud: control plane node, ML training nodes (worker nodes)

On Edge: ML serving nodes (worker nodes)

I've read in the documentation:

https://docs.k3s.io/advanced#node-labels-and-taints

that is possible to create dedicated nodes for specific workloads.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. if the above proposed architecture is feasible from the point of view of K3s
2. if for example I'm running on the Cloud, MinIO as a service in K3s with bucket, s3://my_bucket, can I accessed it from the Edge in the same way with s3://my_bucket?
3. what configuration do I need on the Edge, in order to access a bucket created on MinIO on the Cloud?

I've created a support ticket to k3s here: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/8628

I look forward for our support.
Thank you.